# Exact copy of a WP theme is not the same

Tags: php, css, wordpress, themes

Am I missing something very obvious? Running this in my themes directory (wp-content/themes)

```
cp -r myTheme newTheme
```

doesn't seem to produce an exact copy. I can see the menu functioning differently.
This is running locally against the same database and same url.
The only change I make is the name of the them in styles.css so the admin can use that to switch the theme.

Also running

```
diff -arq myTheme newTheme
```

shows no differences except the style.css when I have changed the theme name and nothing prior to that. This is Unix(Macbook Air).
Is something saved to the database that I am unaware of when switching themes or some odd caching issue?

Comment: Theme names are used in the wp db for theme settings, theme options... So if the name is different you won't get all the data stored in db related to the 'other' theme which has a different name.

Comment: Thought there must be something like that. Will go hunting for some settings. Tx

Comment: Use wp's import/export tool to export settings, options... from the source active theme and import them into the destination active theme. Works fine most of the times. If not, then you need to do some db work.

Comment: @Arbel Thanks. There appears to have just been a main menu set up for the navigation that needed to be set for the new theme.That solved my issue.

Comment: @BooB You are welcome. Glad to be of help to you.

Comment: Actually still having some more display issues. What other settings should I be looking at? Is it only the Theme settings or are plugins, widgets etc saved against the theme too?

Comment: 'Some display issues' is very broad and not specific. But generally speaking plugin settings are stored separately than theme settings. Exporting and importing most probably will work just fine. Did you try it?